# How to make List Items clickable individually from one another in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make each individual list item clickable.
Here I have a color change state so that the color changes to red. But everytime I click one list item, it makes all of the boxes red. Again I want to select which ones to turn red, not turn all of them red. a hint in the right direction or a link would do fine.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import MainTool from './components/Layout/MainTool/MainTool.js';
    import Aux from './hoc/Aux.js';

    class App extends Component {

      state = {
        MainList: [
          "GamePlay",
          "Visuals",
          "Audio",
          "Story"
        ],
        color: "white"
      }

      changeEle = () =>{
        this.setState({color : "red"});
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <Aux>
            <MainTool MainList = {this.state.MainList}
            change = {this.changeEle}
            color = {this.state.color}/>
          </Aux>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

This MainTool just shoots my state arguments to Checkblock. Just for reference. Its unlikely the error is here although I have been wrong plenty times before.

```
import React from 'react';
import './MainTool.css';
import CheckBlock from '../../CheckBlock/CheckBlock';

const MainTool = props => {
    return (
        <div className = "mtborder">
            <CheckBlock MainList = {props.MainList}
            change = {props.change}
            color = {props.color}/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MainTool;
```

And here is my best guess at where the problem is. I used a loop to iterate through my state object array and print out the list and divs next to each list item. the divs being the elements I want to make clickable individually.

```
import React from 'react';
import './CheckBlock.css';
import Aux from '../../hoc/Aux';

const CheckBlock = props => {

console.log(props.change);
console.log(props.color);

    let mainList = [];

    for(let i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        mainList[i] = <li key = {i} 
        className = "nameBox">{props.MainList[i]}
        <div onClick = {props.change} 
        style = {{backgroundColor: props.color}} 
        className = "clickBox"></div></li>
    }

    //console.log(dubi());

    return (
        <Aux>
            <ul className = "mainList">{mainList}</ul>
            <button>Enter</button>
        </Aux>
    );
};

export default CheckBlock;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a state based ListItem component with internal color state. No need to pass function as prop to change color. Use internal  method

```js
class ListItem extends Component {
  state = { color : 'white' };
  onClick = () => {
     this.setState({ color: 'red' });
  }
  render () {
       return (
        <li key={i} className="nameBox">
            {this.props.value}
         <div onClick={this.onClick} style={{backgroundColor: props.color}} 
    className="clickBox">
        </div>
       </li>
   );
  }
}


const CheckBlock = props => {

   console.log(props.change);
   console.log(props.color);

    let mainList = [];

    for(let i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        mainList[i] = <ListItem key={i} value={props.MainList[i]} />

    }


       return (
        <Aux>
            <ul className = "mainList">{mainList}</ul>
            <button>Enter</button>
        </Aux>
       );
};
```

Comment: You are using one state to change color, within a component state will apply for all the list item. Either you can add red color on the basis of click index. Fir that assign class to all of the list, on click call a function in which get all the list item by documents.getElementsByClassName and then add style color on the basis of your click list item. Second way you can make separate component for each list item, then every list item will have its own state and you can change color of any.

Answer (score 0):

I put jsfiddle together:

Let me know if there is a better practice to toggle element in React;

Cheers!

- [List item toggle jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michaelscraft/7kr350mh/)

```
// ----------------APP-------------------
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    mainList: [
      {
        label: 'GamePlay',
        id: 1,
      },
      {
        label: 'Visuals',
        id: 2,
      },
      {
        label: 'Audio',
        id: 3,
      },
      {
        label: 'Story',
        id: 4,
      },
    ],
  }

  render() {
    const { mainList } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <List mainList={mainList} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
// ----------------LIST-------------------
const List = ({ mainList }) => (
  <div>
    {mainList.map((listItem) => {
      const { label, id } = listItem;

      return (
        <ListItem key={id} id={id} label={label} />
      );
    })}
  </div>
);
```

```
// ----------------LIST-ITEM-------------------
class ListItem extends React.Component{
    state = {
      selected: false,
    }

    changeColor = () => {
      const { selected } = this.state;

      this.setState({selected: !selected})
    }

    render(){
      const { label, id } = this.props;
      const { selected } = this.state;

      return console.log(selected ,' id - ', id ) || (
        <button 
          className={selected ? 'green' : 'red'}
          onClick= {() => this.changeColor()}
        >
          {label}
        </button>
    )   
  }
}
```